# Check if a Point is on Arc

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have a point with x,y,z co-ordinates. I have an arc,Its bulge, center point, midpoint,start point, end point,start angle and end angle. All i need to check is if the point exist on that arc or not..Kindly Help. Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Found out the answer by myself. I just calculated the distance between my target point and center point. If its equal to the radius and the bulge formed by connecting the discovered point is equal with the default mid point, then it lies on arc,

Answer (score 0):

Since you are giving virtually no information in the question, you cannot expect much precision in the answer. Take the (parametric?) equation describing your curve, look at its $x$, $y$, $z$ coordinates; choose one that looks the least complicated (for instance if one of the coordinates progresses in a linear fashion, use that one). Solve the equation saying that the chosen coordinate is equal to the one of your point; unless something unusual is going on there will be finitely many solutions. Then for those values test of the other two coordinates match up with you point; if for one of the solution both other cordinates match the point is on the curve, otherwise it is not.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand which pieces of information characterizing the arc are available. In the special case when two endpoints and the midpoint of the arc are given, the three points make an isosceles triangle. Suppose $x$ is the distance of the midpoint $B$ from endpoints $A$ or $C$ and $y$ is the distance between endpoints $A$ and $C$. Let $D$ be the midpoint of chord $AC$, $O$ be the center of the circle, and $r$ its radius.

If $y>x\sqrt{2}$, the arc subtends less than $180^{\circ}$ and $BDO$ is a line segment with $\overline{DO}=r-\sqrt{x^2-(y/2)^2}$. Then, $\overline{AO}=r=\sqrt{\left(r-\sqrt{x^2-(y/2)^2}\right)^2+(y/2)^2}$ yielding $r=x^2/\{2\sqrt{x^2-(y/2)^2}\}$. Using coordinates of $A$, $B$, and $C$, determine center $O$ as $B + ((A+C)/2-B)*r/\sqrt{x^2-(y/2)^2}=B + ((A+C)/2-B)*x^2/(2x^2-y^2/2)$ and check if distance of the point in question from $O$ equals $r$.

If $y<x\sqrt{2}$, the arc subtends more than $180^{\circ}$ and 
$BOD$ is a line segment with $\overline{DO}=\sqrt{x^2-(y/2)^2}-r$. Then, $\overline{AO}=r=\sqrt{\left(\sqrt{x^2-(y/2)^2}-r\right)^2+(y/2)^2}$. The rest of steps remain the same as above.

Answer (score 0):

sp: start point of the arc.
mp: mid. point of the arc. mp is not necessary to be the center on the arc.
ep: end point of the arc.
cp: center of the circle. (arc)
r: radius of the circle. (arc)
p: the point that you want check.
first, check p is on the same circle defined by sp, ep and cp. (match to plane equation and range from cp is same to r)
second,
v1 = sp-mp (vector)
v2 = ep-mp (vector)
get angle between v1 and v2 by cosine formula.
v1' = sp-p (vector)
v2' = ep-p (vector)
get angle' between v1' and v2' by cosine formula.
the p is on the arc if (angle == angle'). consider some fudge factor if use PC.
you also have to decide how to treat p is same to sp or ep.